# replacing fonts on webpages (webkit)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, webkit

I want to replace every font on every webpage be replaced by "OpenDyslexic" font. When user types web address, it should load the webpage and use this font on any text (google.com is preloaded).

```
import SwiftUI
import WebKit
import AVFoundation

private let dyslexicFontName = "OpenDyslexic-Regular"

struct Browser: View {
    @State private var urlString: String = "www.google.com"
    @State private var webView: WKWebView = WKWebView()
    @State private var isLoading: Bool = false
    @State private var isError: Bool = false
    private var synthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            WebViewWrapper(webView: webView)
                .frame(height: 580)
                .offset(x: 0, y: -85)

            if isError {
                Text("Incorrect URL")
                    .font(.custom(dyslexicFontName, size: 20))
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.red)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    .padding()
                    .onAppear {
                        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 2, repeats: false) { _ in
                            withAnimation {
                                isError = false
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }

            VStack {
                Spacer()

                HStack {
                    TextField("Enter URL", text: $urlString, onCommit: {
                        loadURL()
                    })
                    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                    .font(Font.custom(dyslexicFontName, size: 20))
                    .autocapitalization(.none)
                    .padding()
                    .frame(height: 50)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    .offset(x: 0, y: 220)

                    Button(action: {
                        loadURL()
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "arrow.right.circle.fill")
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
                    }
                    .offset(x: 0, y: 220)

                    Button(action: {
                        UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "keyboard.chevron.compact.down")
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
                    }
                    .padding()
                    .offset(x: 0, y: 220)
                }

                Rectangle()
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    .frame(height: 300)
                    .offset(x: 0, y: 225)
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            // peload google.com
            loadURL()
        }
    }

    private func loadURL() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://" + urlString) else {
            isError = true
            return
        }

        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        webView.load(request)
        isError = false
    }
}

struct WebViewWrapper: UIViewRepresentable {
    let webView: WKWebView

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        let view = webView
        view.navigationDelegate = context.coordinator
        view.configuration.userContentController.add(context.coordinator, name: "callbackHandler")
        return view
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, WKNavigationDelegate, WKScriptMessageHandler {
        var parent: WebViewWrapper

        init(_ parent: WebViewWrapper) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

        func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
        }
        
        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
            injectFontJavaScript(webView)
        }

        private func injectFontJavaScript(_ webView: WKWebView) {
            let fontInjectionScript = """
                var style = document.createElement('style');
                style.appendChild(document.createTextNode('@font-face { font-family: "opendyslexic"; src: url("http://dyslexicfonts.com/fonts/OpenDyslexic-Regular.otf") format("opentype"); } * { font-family: "opendyslexic" !important; }'));
                document.head.appendChild(style);
            """
            webView.evaluateJavaScript(fontInjectionScript, completionHandler: nil)
        }
    }
}

struct Browser_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Browser()
    }
}
```

However, I see that the font was changed, but not loaded. Can someone help me replace every piece of text on the webpage with OpenDyslexic? (It's bundled with app: OpenDyslexic-Regular)

I have tried everything, but nothing worked. I even tried to inject css or js.